# HTML forms - difference between 'action' and the 'next' variable?

Tags: html, forms, redirect

According to the HTML book which I am reading (and according to here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) it says that in the case of forms:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
```

'action' specifies where to send the form data when a form is submitted. The syntax for it could be

```
<form action="URL">
```

Now, in the book I am reading, it also talks about a hidden 'next' variable, like so:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='next' value='/' />
<input type='submit' value='login' />
```

The book I am reading states that

```
The form contains a submit button as well as a hidden field called 'next'. This hidden variable contains a URL that tells where to redirect the user after they have logged in.
```

From my understanding, doesn't 'action' either way tell specify where to redirect to after the form has been submitted? So isn't having the hidden 'next' variable not necessary because 'action' already tells where to redirect to? Which takes priority if action and next are different URLs? Does it redirect to the URL in action or the URL in next?

Comment: there is no "next" field in standard html, book use this as example of field which is processed by some server-side script, which should be written by you to make redirect from page where form is submitted to "next" page

Comment: @Lashane right, but doesn't 'action' already say where to redirect to after the form is submitted?

Comment: `next` is an example like Lashane said. I don't generally use hidden, but it may be good if you need to submit an id that the user should not be able to see/modify.

Comment: action is used to indicate where form will be submitted, so in some sense - yes, by submitting form we're redirected to new page

Comment: @Lashane oh okay I get it now, action just says where the form is submitted but that doesn't necessairly mean the user NEEDS to be redirected to the same page which the form is submitted to. So action just shows where to submit form, and if there is a next variable, then the user gets redirected to next. If there is no next variable, then user gets redirected to where the form is submitted, correct?

Comment: no, form is just submitted to url in "action", server-side script returns some page to browser or can redirect to another page

Comment: @Lashane what happens if next is not declared? Where will it redirect the user after the user submits the form? Will it redirect to the same page or will it redirect to 'action'? (Sorry, I would try it but currently I'm just reading a textbook and cannot try it right now).

Comment: forget about next, it is just example in book, it means nothing

Comment: @Lashane I need to know because I am going to be doing server-sided stuff and form handling soon. What happens if there is no next and a user submits a POST form? Will it redirect the user to the same page or will it redirect the user to 'action'?

Comment: if there is no next - nothing will happen, if there is next - nothing will happen, this field do nothing, the only attribute which is used by browser - "action", to this URL data from form will be posted, so actually there is no redirection at all. but you can write script which will redirect user somewhere, one of possible variants - this script will read some posted value (for example supernextpage or just next or mynextpage - name decided by you) and actually redirect (by redirect I mean send 30x header code with location)

Comment: The `form` goes to the log in page passing along the value in in the `hidden` input with the name `next`.  That value is where the user is to be redirected after log in (or possibly if the log in fails).  Click `submit` the `form` makes a call to the url in the `action` attribute, then what ever happens at the url the user is then redirect to what `next` passed along in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up the action attribute has **nothing** to do with redirection.

When you click a submit button in a form the browser sends an HTTP request to the server, specificaly to the resource mentioned in the action attribute, using either `get` or `post`. What happens next is entirely dependant on what you are using server side.

As far as I am aware the presense of a `Next` property in the request has no special meaning.

Normally when a form is submitted one of two things will happen

- The server does some process then return an HTTP Response. This will show the action url in the address bar of the browser
- The server does some processing then redirects the user to a new page. This is usualy programmed by you the programmer and does not happen automagicaly. In php you would use `http_redirect(someURL)`. The `next` hidden field could be used to hold this URL but it won't do anything with it by itself.

On a technical note, http redirects, be they with asp, php, etc cause, an additional round trip to the browser. So in the case of the redirect above, an HTTP Response is send to the broswser with a header indicating to redirect and where to direct to. The browser will then send a new request to the new location. This is why the new address appears in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Action url is where the page will be redirected to, by default. The value of next has no effect unless you have server side code to do that. Even if you do write code, the redirect will first go to action url and then to any other url you have changed.